# Execution tree meta interpreting

Tags: prolog, interpreter, execution, prolog-metainterpreter

I have tracing meta-interpreter made from my previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235148/implementing-cut-in-tracing-meta-interpreter-prolog/) and I would like to make similar meta-interpreter but this time for making execution trees. 
I've made something like this below using similar to same code found on the web and techniques from my previous questions.

```
clause_tree(true,_,true) :- !, true. 
clause_tree((G,R),Trail,(TG,TR)) :-
   !, 
   clause_tree(G,Trail,TG),
   clause_tree(R,Trail,TR). 
clause_tree(G,_,prolog(G)) :- 
   (predicate_property(G,built_in) ;  
     predicate_property(G,compiled) ), 
    call(G).
clause_tree(G,Trail,tree(G,T)) :- 
   clause(G,Body),
   clause_tree(Body,[G|Trail],T).

why(G) :-
    call_with_depth_limit( 
        catch(
            clause_tree(G,[],T),
            cut,
            fail),
        30,
        _Message),
    nl,
    draw_tree(T,0).

draw_tree(tree(Root,Branches),Tab) :- !,
   tab(Tab),
   write(Tab),
   write(': '),
   write(Root),
   nl,
   Tab1 is Tab + 1,
   draw_tree(Branches,Tab1).
draw_tree((B,Bs),Tab) :- !,
   draw_tree(B,Tab),
   draw_tree(Bs,Tab).
draw_tree(Node,Tab) :-
   tab(Tab),
   write(Tab),
   write(': '),
   write(Node),
   nl.

%example program for testing
%?-p(X).
p(X) :- a(X). 
p(X) :- b(X),c(X), d(X),e(X). 
p(X) :- f(X).

b(Y) :- g(Y), h(Y).
b(1). 
b(2). 

a(1).

c(1). 
c(2).

d(1). 
d(2). 

e(2). 

f(3). 

g(2).
g(1).

h(2).
```

How can I alter this interpreter that it displays branches that fails and that tree is only one with all solutions? Consider that trees are done only for similar programs like example program written in code if that matters.

I am using swi-prolog.

Edit : I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/f3_1_1.gif) but in textual form.

Comment: You will have to reify variable bindings, backtracking - all of this. I'd suggest, first study how to reify backtracking in Prolog with a much smaller meta-interpreter.