# Meta-interpreting logical cut in Prolog (Edited to accommodate comments)

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut, prolog-metainterpreter

I am implementing a geometric theorem prover in Sicstus Prolog; and in order to get over the problem of backtracking over I/O, I am using a meta-interpreter. This last however does not seem to handle cuts as expected.

My meta-interpreter looks like the following. The first argument to `solve/5` is the goal to be evaluated, the second and third arguments allow me to control the search depth, and the fourth and fifth arguments are for handling backtracking over output.

```
solve(true,_,_, O, O) :- 
        !.
solve(_,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, _, _) :- 
        CurrentDepth > DepthLimit, 
        !, 
        fail.
solve(nl,_,_, O, [nl|O]):- !.
solve(write(X),_,_, O, [X|O]):- !.
solve((A,B),CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2) :- 
        !, 
        solve(A,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O1),
        solve(B,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O1, O2).
solve((A;B),CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2) :- 
        !, 
        (
                (solve(A,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2); 
                solve(B,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2))
        ).

solve(A,_,_, O, O) :-
        (
                predicate_property(A, built_in);
                predicate_property(A, imported_from(lists))
        ),
        !,
        call(A).
solve(Goal,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O1) :-  
        !,        
        predicate_property(Goal, interpreted),!,        
        NewDepth is CurrentDepth+1,!,        
        clause(Goal,SubGoals),
        solve(SubGoals,NewDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O1).
```

I have followed the instructions in the thread [Implementing cut in tracing meta interpreter prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235148/implementing-cut-in-tracing-meta-interpreter-prolog)
and changed the meta-interpreter to the following.

```
solve(true,_,_, O, O) :- 
        !.
solve(_,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, _, _) :- 
        CurrentDepth > DepthLimit, 
        !, 
        fail.
solve(nl,_,_, O, [nl|O]):- !.
solve(write(X),_,_, O, [X|O]):- !.
solve(!, _,_,_,_):- !, ( true ; throw(cut)).
solve((A,B),CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2) :- 
        !, 
        solve(A,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O1),
        solve(B,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O1, O2).
solve((A;B),CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2) :- 
        !, 
        (
                (solve(A,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2); 
                solve(B,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O2))
        ).
solve(A,_,_, O, O) :-
        (
                predicate_property(A, built_in);
                predicate_property(A, imported_from(lists))
        ),
        !,
        call(A).
solve(Goal,CurrentDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O1) :-  
        !,        
        predicate_property(Goal, interpreted),!,        
        NewDepth is CurrentDepth+1,!,        
        clause(Goal,SubGoals),
        catch(
                (       
                        solve(SubGoals,NewDepth,DepthLimit, O0, O1)
                ),
                cut,
                fail
        ).
```

However now, `solve/5` fails for some of the problems fed to the theorem prover. It is worth noting that I do not have any of the predicates `call/1`, `catch/3`, or `throw/1` in my theorem prover. An example problem is the following.

```
:- dynamic test_goal/2.
:- dynamic predicate_with_small_depth/2.
:- dynamic predicate_with_large_depth/2.
:- dynamic p_1/2.
:- dynamic p_2/2.
:- dynamic p_3/2.
:- dynamic p_4/2.
:- dynamic p_5/2.

test_goal(X,Y):-
        predicate_with_small_depth(X,Y),!,
        predicate_with_large_depth(X,Y).

predicate_with_small_depth(X,Y):-
        X < Y,
        write('Small Depth Outcome 1'), nl.

predicate_with_small_depth(X,Y):-
        X > Y,
        write('Small Depth Outcome 2'), nl.

predicate_with_large_depth(X,Y):-
        p_1(X,Y).

p_1(X,Y):- p_2(X,Y).

p_2(X,Y):- p_3(X,Y).

p_3(X,Y):- p_4(X,Y).

p_4(X,Y):- p_5(X,Y).

p_5(X,Y):-    
        predicate_with_small_depth(X,Y),!,    
        write('Large Depth Outcome: '), write(X), write(' '), write(Y), nl.
```

If the goal `solve(test_goal(1,2),0,8,O1,O2)` is evaluated, Prolog's answer using the modified meta-interpreter is:

`O2 = [nl,2,' ',1,'Large Depth Outcome: '|_A] ?`

but the answer should be

`O2 = [nl,2,' ',1,'Large Depth Outcome: ',nl,'Small Depth Outcome 1',nl,'Small Depth Outcome 1'|O1] ?`

which is the one given by my meta-interpreter prior to adding the cut adaptation.

Does the new meta-interpreter implementation look correct in terms of handling the cut operator?

Many thanks.

---

EDIT

In trying to identify the problem set and way to solve the problems in the comments below the following was made apparent:

1. > the [TGTP](http://hilbert.mat.uc.pt/TGTP/) contains the kind of problems that my program tackles
2. [Geometric Theorem Proving](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~janos/COURSES/THPR-2015/quaresma-geometry.pdf) by Pedro Quaresma, Days in Logic 2012, University of Evora, 6-8 February 2012

   (Gelernter's work) best capture my program.

   Slies: 27/99

[image]

and 28/99

[image]

also

> The cut is necessary for me as it allows the program to stop working
>   on alternative solutions of a given goal once one solution is found.
>   For example, if I have

```
prove(X):-(p1(X),!);(p2(X),!);p3(X), if p1(X) is satisfiable,
```

> I do not want other solutions via p2/1 and p3/1 to be
>   found. This saves a lot of computation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195442/discussion-on-question-by-amine-marref-meta-interpreting-logical-cut-in-prolog).

Comment: You need to rephrase this more tactfully. For example: "The comments took a chatty turn, it is best they are moved to chat".

Comment: Not related to the cut issue, but the clause for `nl` should probably record `'\n'` instead of the atom `nl`. Otherwise you can not distinguish between the goals `write(nl)` and `nl`.

Answer (score 2):

The clause for cut is incorrect. The clause for cut should record the written data the same way as the clause for `true`. I think you want:

```
solve(!, _,_,O,O):- !, ( true ; throw(cut)).
```