# committing to choices in the scope of catch/3

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut, prolog-metainterpreter

The following is small prolog meta-interpreter that interprets the cut using the catch/throw mechanism[1].

```
fruit(apple).
fruit(orange) :- !.
fruit(banana).

% meta-interpreter that handles the cut
prove(true) :- !.
prove(!) :- !, ( true ; throw(cut) ).
prove((A,B)):- !, prove(A), prove(B).
prove(H) :- 
    catch((clause(H,B), prove(B)), cut, fail).
```

With plain prolog:

```
?- fruit(X).
X = apple
X = orange
```

... and with the meta-interpreter, the results are as expected:

```
?- prove(fruit(X)).
X = apple
X = orange
```

**Question**

My question is about retention of choices made within the scope of `catch(Goal, ExceptionTag, Handler)`.

**Q1:** The SWI-Prolog documentation for `catch/3`[2] is not clear. But it suggests that all choices made inside Goal are discarded when an exception is raised. This, to me, doesn't accord with the observed behaviour. If all choices are lost, then `prove(!):-true` would not remain committed to, which would then not result in `X=orange` as a solution.

What am I misunderstanding about the behaviour of `catch/3`?

**Q2:** Even if the choices are retained, the effect of `Handler=fail` means the entire scope `((clause(H,B), prove(B))` should fail, again disgarding any choices made in that  `Goal`.

Clearly I am misunderstanding something here.

---

**My Attempt At Diagnosis**

I changed the meta-interpreter to be more verbose at the areas of interest:

```
prove(!) :- writeln("111"), true.
prove(!) :- writeln("222"), throw(cut), writeln("333").
```

The output confirms that the choice associated with `prove(!)-writeln("111"),true` is retained - apparently in contradiction with the documentation.

```
?- prove(fruit(X)),
X = apple
111
222
X = orange
```

In addition to SWI-Prolog I've googled the documentation of implementations and they aren't clear either.

---

**UPDATE:**

Given the comments I am highlighting the SWI-Prolog documentation for `catch/3`:

> all choice points generated by Goal are cut, the system backtracks to the start of catch/3

This suggests that all solutions are lost, as if the Goal in `catch(Goal, Exception, Handler)` was not executed.

---

1. [Implementing cut in tracing meta interpreter prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235148/implementing-cut-in-tracing-meta-interpreter-prolog/27255452#27255452)
2. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=catch/3

Comment: thanks @jschimpf - this the answer to the question. If you wanted to copy/paste this into your full answer, I'll mark is as complete.

Comment: Glad it helped @Penelope - I moved the comment into my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time your query succeeds with the second solution (`X = orange`), no exception has been raised yet, and no choices have been discarded.

Only when you then ask for a further solution, does execution fail to the right hand side of `( ... ; throw(cut) )`. Only then is the exception raised, discarding any remaining alternatives of the `fruit(X)` call.

So, this metainterpreted implementation is lazy: it discards alternatives only on failure, while a typical implementation would discard them immediately at cut time. This difference does not affect the semantics, only resource consumption. Either implementation is valid in principle.

EDIT: You seem to slightly misinterpret the documentation. To clarify: `catch(Goal,...,...)` behaves like `call(Goal)` up to the moment that a `throw` is encountered. It may well first succeed with multiple solutions. When the `throw` is executed, only the *remaining* choices are cut. And *backtracking to the start of catch/3* only means that all of Goal's bindings at throw-time are undone before the recovery goal executes. Earlier successes cannot be undone.

Comment: hi @jschimpf thanks for replying. quick clarifications: (1) why doesn't the `fail` handler in `catch` fail the entire scope of its goal, which means all solutions found by `prove(B)`.. isn't that what the documentation for catch/3 says? (2) lazy implementation.. does that mean other prologs wont do this? is this ISO standard?

Answer (score 1):

This clause creates two choice points:

```
%   |------- #1 ----------|--- #2 -----|
    prove(!) :- !, ( true ; throw(cut) ).
```

The first choice point will simply succeed. This is producing the `X = orange` solution. You can see it in this trace (using `trace/0` in SWI):

```
^  Redo: (14) clause(fruit(_7766), _9820) ? creep
^  Exit: (14) clause(fruit(orange), !) ? creep
   Call: (14) prove(!) ? creep
   Call: (15) true ? creep
   Exit: (15) true ? creep
   Exit: (14) prove(!) ? creep
^  Exit: (12) catch(user:(clause(fruit(orange), !), prove(!)), cut, user:fail) ? creep
   Exit: (11) prove(fruit(orange)) ? creep
X = orange ;
```

Notice how `throw/1` was never called. Next it will redo on `prove(!)` but from its #2 choice point this time which will throw:

```
   Redo: (14) prove(!) ? creep
   Call: (15) throw(cut) ? creep
   Exception: (15) throw(cut) ? creep
   Exception: (14) prove(!) ? creep
   Fail: (11) prove(fruit(_18)) ? creep
false.
```

Now it throws, catches, and fails, emulating the cut behavior.

TL;DR: `(true ; throw(foo) )` does not throw immediately, it first succeeds and then only throws upon backtracking.

Comment: hi @gureg do you know why the fail handler doesn't fail the entire scope of the catch goal and therefore invalidate all solutions? isn't this what the documentation for catch/3 says?

Comment: @Penelope Cuts don't remove solutions that have already been proven. Maybe it'll help if you think of it as cutting _remaining_ choice points. Consider the query: `?- X = 1; X = 2; !, fail`. It will still report the answers X = 1 and X = 2.  `?- X = 1; X = 2; !, fail ; X = 3.` will _not_ report `X = 3` because that choice point gets cut.

Comment: hi @guregu - thanks, your example is how we expect cut to work. In the swi-prolog documentation it says "" all choice points generated by Goal are cut, the system backtracks to the start of catch/3 while preserving the thrown exception term "" .. which suggests that all solutions found inside the Goal are lost. The Goal here being the first parameter of catch/3 .. which in this case is the grouped goal ( clause(H,B), prove(B) ). I this THIS is the root cause of my confusion.